# Data entry through Jmeter not reflected in UI of application

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, moodle

I'm using Jmeter to perform load test on Moodle application

I followed the below steps to replicate a simple "add company " test scenario

1: Recorded the browser actions through HTTP Test script recorder and created a test plan with thread user of 1

2: Added HTTP Cache Manager,Added regular expression extractor for retrieving dynamically generated session for login HTTP request.

3. For Http request of adding new company, addded user parameters containing new company name
4. I run the test, everything seems ok in the view results tree- response section (response code: 200,response message:OK), all the required variables are passed in the HTTP POST

**PROBLEM: New company added through Jmeter test is not reflected in UI of the moodle action**
 Can any of you please let me know
Is there something I could be missing or anyway I can debug the problem?

P.S: I'm new to Jmeter and looked around a lot for data inputted through Jmeter not being displayed in the UI of the web application,dint find useful results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to questions of this sort is almost always that you missed some necessary dynamic value besides session ID which you did catch.

An `HTTP200` response just means the server returned a "good" response. Which could also happily contain an error message.

I would check the actual html body of the returned response for any errors. Checking the log on the server side can give you clues to what went wrong sometimes. You should also try adding a cookie manager.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had actually added Cookie manager din't mention it. But the session id which I extract through regular expression extractor is passed only when I check "Use multipart/form-data for POST" of HTTP Request, even though file attachment is not necessary. Could this affect data update being affected in any way?

Comment: You were right, I thought I was passing the session variable , but it was not being passed. I used regex extractor to extract the session id and passed it as ${session} but this value is not being captured in HTTP POST, my post data is as follows , please let me know if that is something you could help with
"POST data:
id=633&action=edit&sessionID=${session}&name=1234567&submitbutton=Submit "
Note- my regex works fine, I checked with the regex debug

Comment: Is regex not storing session id in the parameter correctly? Or it stores it correctly but you're not able to recall the value properly? Can you show your regex extractor, and how you're using session? screenshots from your test plan would be helpful.

Comment: I was not extracting the session value where I was supposed, Put the regex extractor for the correct HTTP request. It works fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Run your test with 1 virtual user in GUI mode with [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener enabled and inspect responses to see where your scripts fails. My expectation is that you simply cannot log in.

See [Moodle-JMeter-LoadTest.jmx](https://moodle.org/pluginfile.php/135/mod_forum/attachment/1047234/Moodle-JMeter-LoadTest.jmx.zip) file for reference, it uses [XPath Extractor](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) to get session key and course id.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can test using JMeter. Try JUnit Test cases instead http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/junitsampler_tutorial.pdf

Comment: Please support your claim that this cannot be done in JMeter. This sounds like pure HTTP calls, which is the JMeter's primary use case. Moreover OP states they're trying to perform a load test. How is JUnit more appropriate than JMeter?